# android google map get md5 error cmd

Tags: android, google-maps, cmd

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/)

I tried to get MD5 like this

[image: attempt to get MD5]

I got `C:\Program is not regonized` error.

What am I doing wrong please?

I am logged in as Adminstrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you also need to wrap `keytools.exe` path inside quotes(`"`) like:

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\<path-to-jdk-dir>\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias 
    androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\users\<user-name>\.android\debug.keystore" 
    -storepass android -keypass android
```